# Default Tab Navigation getting stuck for Autocomplete type text box in Mozilla Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I am new in world of jquery and javascript. So please sorry if I am using and asking for stupid code.

In MVC based project, Normal Navigation of Tab button get stuck over autocomplete type text box in Mozilla Firefox browser. On Tab key press it's not moving to next element. Working fine in IE and Chrome. Can anyone assist me to fix this? I am not much friendly with Jquery and Javascript but it seems issue is related to Jquery/Javascript.

I have generated fiddler for this issue. Complete code of Jquery is posted there. In fiddler it will work fine. But I am facing issue on Updated/latest Firefox. Please assist me to fix this issue. Thanks.
I think issue will be somewhere in these lines. Link of fiddler is mentioned below.

```
case keyCode.TAB:
                    if ( !self.menu.active ) {
                        return;
                    }
                    self.menu.select( event );
                    break;

https://jsfiddle.net/3envs5zf/7/
```